# How to fetch correct data from database with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

In my project, I use ajax to fetch data from DB. And I test the data content, I choose alert(valData) in success function. But unlucky, nothing return from 
ajax. I tested

```
select contact from IDC WHERE id=5;
```

It works fine in mysql cmd line.

Here is my js code:

```
var stNum = 5;
$.ajax({
        dataType:'json',
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_ajax_csc.php",
        data:{stNum:stNum},
        success:function(data) 
        {
         var valData = data;
         alert(valData);
        }
      });
```

Here is get_ajax_csc.php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['stNum']))
{   
 include("DB.php"); 
 $q=$_POST["stNum"];
 $sql="select contact from IDC WHERE id='".$q."';";
 $sel = $conn->query($sql); 

 $arr = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 echo $arr['contact'];
 }

if(isset($_POST['htmlCnt']))
{   
include("DB.php");
$htcnt=stripslashes(".$_POST['htmlCnt'].");
........ 
}
 ?>
```

Here is DB.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$pwd=$_SESSION['password'];
$user=$_SESSION['user'];

try 
{
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=x.x.x.x;port=3306;dbname=hpc',$user,$pwd);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  echo "account or pwd wrong <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=index.html'>";
    exit;
}  
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, true);
?>
```

It seems nothing wrong in my code, but I cann't fetch data from DB

I have no idea about the error, who can help me ?

Comment: Open developers console, check errors.

Comment: Please, please, dont store your password and user in the session. It is terribly insecure.

Comment: Press F12 with Chrome -> Network -> find your request and check out if all data is correct.

Comment: $sql="select contact from IDC WHERE id='".$q."';"; why you use ' ' id is an int. header('Content-type: application/json') on get_ajax_csc.php

Comment: dataType:'json' => expect json in return,  echo $arr['contact']; => is this json ? if not, you're in error callback on ajax

Comment: for print use json_encode( $arr['contact']); not echo ..in php file(get_ajax_csc)

Comment: @stack First you have to check $arr['contact']; has some value in get_ajax_csc.php. For test you can echo with static value Ex. echo 'test '.$arr['contact'];

Comment: @Erik, I know store password and user in cookie is dangerous. But session is in the server, besides i need user and password to log on database when another page is clicked. I don't know why you say it is insecure? but how?

Comment: @daheda, I have tested that it doesn't matter between id is an int and $q is string. where id=5 and where id='5' are both working fine. The key is dataType:'json'.  Delete it , and works fine.

Comment: @BSB, i have tested $arr['contact'] has right value. stripslashes meth makes ajax return nothing, see my update in get_ajax_csc.php code.But I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

The data that you send back from the server to the client is not a valid json data as you have specify in the ajax that you are expecting a json data.

Also your queries are not the same :

```
SELECT contact from IDC WHERE id=5; // This is the correct query you run on the cmd line.



$sql="select contact from IDC WHERE id='".$q."';"; // This is the one from your php
```

if you take a close look at the queries the first one id is treated as an integer on the second one as a string. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Also you are using PDO so take the advantage of using prepared statements.
Try the below code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['stNum'])) {
    include("DB.php");

    $q   = $_POST["stNum"];
    $sql = "select contact from IDC WHERE id= ? ";

    $sel = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $sel->bindParam(1, $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sel->execute();
    $arr = $sel->fetchColumn(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($arr['contact']); //send back json data to the client
}
?>
```

Comment: on my god, stripslashes makes ajax return nothing. It is not about integer as a string, see get_ajax_csc.php code update

Comment: what do you mean? I have tried many times that without stripslashes(), Div content can not be update to my database.